# Qual a diferença entre estes dois tipos de definição de valores padrões?

Tags: c#

Em **C#**, ao criar uma `classe` nova com algumas propriedades, devo definir algum valor padrão para as propriedades criadas, **0** no caso de uma propriedade de *SaldoAtual*.

Qual seria a diferença das 2 maneiras a seguir que representam a situação acima? Teria algum problema futuro em usar a primeira ou a segunda? Qual seria a melhor?

Primeira maneira:

```
using System;

public class Correntista
{
    public double SaldoAtual { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Segunda maneira:

```
using System;

public class Correntista
{
    public Correntista()
    {
        SaldoAtual = 0;
    }

    public double SaldoAtual { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nenhuma[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337075)

Comment: Um detalhe importante: isso é uma característica da linguagem, não tem relação com qualquer framework web. Portanto as tags ASP.NET-MVC (_framework para trabalhar com MVC em ASP.NET_), ASP.NET (_framework para desenvolver .NET para a web_) e ASP (_outra tecnoliga, completamente diferente_) são desnecessárias para esta pergunta.

Comment: Apesar de não haver diferenças na prática, deixei uma resposta interessante pra quem é curioso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na prática não há nenhuma diferença. O valor padrão para a propriedade será inserido na chamada do construtor.

Porém, analisando os dois códigos IL gerados, pode-se notar uma breve diferença entre os dois. Veja abaixo o código referente ao método construtor gerado para os dois casos.

**Caso 1** - Valor inserido no construtor:

```
Correntista..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  call        UserQuery+Correntista.set_SaldoAtual
IL_000F:  nop         
IL_0010:  ret
```

**Caso 2** - Valor padrão para propriedade:

```
Correntista..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Correntista.<SaldoAtual>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ldarg.0     
IL_0008:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

Percebeu que há duas pequenas diferenças entre eles?

No primeiro caso, primeiramente é feita a chamada da classe base (`Object`) e depois o construtor usa o método **`set_SaldoAtual`** para alterar o valor do campo.

Já no segundo caso, inicialmente é feita a alteração do valor do campo, porém **sem fazer uso** do método `set_SaldoAtual`, o valor é inserido diretamente no "campo de apoio" (*backing field*).

Isso realmente não deve mudar nada na prática porque apenas *auto-properties* podem ter um valor padrão. Desta forma, a implementação do método **`set_SaldoAtual`** sempre será apenas fazer com que o *backing field* receba o valor passado para o método.

Comment: Como faço pra verificar os códigos IL gerados?

Comment: @VictorLaio Tem que usar alguma ferramenta pra ver. Eu uso o [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), mas tem o [Ildasm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) e vários outros.

Comment: Obgd pela dica!