# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou com muita dificuldade em resolver um problema de codificação. Quando realizo um *INSERT*, apresenta um erro de referência de objeto não definida na linha `leitora.Tecnico.IdTecnico`. Alguém poderia me dizer o que está ocorrendo?

```
private void bt_gravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tb_numserie.Text == string.Empty || tb_idcategoria.Text == string.Empty || tb_idtecnico.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos obrigatórios", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }

    if (acaoNaTelaSelecionada == AcaoNaTela.Inserir)
    {
        Leitora leitora = new Leitora();

        leitora.IdLeitora = tb_numserie.Text;
        leitora.DataEntrega = dp_data.Value;
        leitora.Tecnico.IdTecnico = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idtecnico.Text);
        leitora.CategoriaLeitora.IdCategoria = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idcategoria.Text);
        leitora.StatusLeitora.IdStatus = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idstatus.Text);

        LeitoraNegocio leitoraNegocio = new LeitoraNegocio();

        string Retorno = leitoraNegocio.Inserir(leitora);

        try
        {
            int IdLeitora = Convert.ToInt32(Retorno);

            MessageBox.Show("Leitora inserida com sucesso. Código: " + IdLeitora.ToString());

            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível inserir. Detalhes: " + Retorno, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace ObjetoTransferencia
{
    public class Leitora
    {
        public string IdLeitora { get; set; }    
        public DateTime DataEntrega { get; set; }    
        public Tecnico Tecnico { get; set; }    
        public CategoriaLeitora CategoriaLeitora { get; set; }    
        public StatusLeitora StatusLeitora { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, Leitora.Tecnico parece estar null.

Comment: Onde ocorre o erro? Não encontrei o trecho onde você inicializa o objeto Tecnico, dentro de Leitora.

Comment: O erro ocorre na quarta linha após o IF - leitora.Tecnico.IdTecnico = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idtecnico.Text);

Answer (score 5):

A propriedade `Tecnico` de `Leitora` está `null` (valor padrão).

Inicialize-a antes de usar

```
Leitora leitora = new Leitora();

leitora.IdLeitora = tb_numserie.Text;
leitora.DataEntrega = dp_data.Value;

leitora.Tecnico = new Tecnico();    

leitora.Tecnico.IdTecnico = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idtecnico.Text);
```

Dependendo da necessidade, pode ser melhor inicializar a instância de `Tecnico` sempre que inicializar uma instância de `Leitora`.

Para isso, você precisaria mudar o valor padrão da propriedade ou adicionar a inicialização no construtor.

```
public class Leitora
{
    public string IdLeitora { get; set; }    
    public DateTime DataEntrega { get; set; }    
    public Tecnico Tecnico { get; set; } = new Tecnico(); 
    // (^) Definindo valor padrão
    public CategoriaLeitora CategoriaLeitora { get; set; }    
    public StatusLeitora StatusLeitora { get; set; }

    public Leitora()
    {
        Tecnico = new Tecnico();
        // Inicialização no construtor
    }
}
```

Escolha apenas um dos dois tipos, talvez seja interessante você ler o posts abaixo.

- [Qual a diferença entre estes dois tipos de definição de valores padrões?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337075/18246); e
- [Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/18246)

Comment: Realmente eu não tinha inicializado. Agora começou a cair no meu exception

Comment: @Gabriel bacana. Só pra constar: se a resposta resolveu o problema da pergunta, você pode marcá-la como correta usando o V do lado direto.